# using std::find_if with std::string

Tags: c++, stl

I'm being stupid here but I can't get the function signature for the predicate going to find_if when iterating over a string:

```
bool func( char );

std::string str;
std::find_if( str.begin(), str.end(), func ) )
```

In this instance google has not been my friend :( Is anyone here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

bool func( char c ) {
    return c == 'x';
}

int main() {
    std::string str ="abcxyz";;
    std::string::iterator it = std::find_if( str.begin(), str.end(), func );
    if ( it != str.end() ) {
        std::cout << "found\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "not found\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, knew I was being stupid, I had the find_if in an if statement and couldn't decipher the error message, thanks

Answer (score 4):

If your're trying to find a single character `c` within a std::string `str` you can probably use `std::find()` rather than `std::find_if()`.  And, actually, you would be better off using `std::string`'s member function [`string::find()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efzty53k.aspx) rather than the function from `<algorithm>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::string str = "abcxyz";
  size_t n = str.find('c');
  if( std::npos == n )
    cout << "Not found.";
  else
    cout << "Found at position " << n;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but not what I was trying to do: I was refactoring an isNumeric function