# Error with listing words without vowels

Tags: c++

Hello I am getting an error `Error'unsigned int std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::find(_Elem,unsigned int) const' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'bool (__cdecl *)(char)' to 'const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &'`
 
When trying to compile this code, it's goal is to remove any words which have vowels in them from MyWords list and then print out the words which have no vowels.

Comment: Just a reminder that `::toupper(c)` is undefined behavior if plain `char` is signed (which it usually is).  And of course, no one who understands what the type `bool` is would write such an if.  Just `return c == 'A' || c == 'E'...;`.  (More likely, of course, you'd just define a `bool isVowel[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = ...;`, and use table lookup.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string::find` takes a sub-string as input and returns the position of the 1st character match.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find

I don't think it can be applied here directly.

Instead, try:

```
bool vowelPresent = false;
for ( int i = 0; i < word1.size(); i++ )
  if ( isVowel( word1[i] ) ) {
    vowelPresent = true;
    break;
  }

if ( !vowelPresent ) {
  cout << word1 << endl;
}
```

Or as Adam suggested, you can use the `std::find_if` function in the `<algorithm>` header.
[using std::find_if with std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767995/using-stdfind-if-with-stdstring)

Comment: This seems to work, It was missing a bracket though `if ( isVowel( word1[i] ))`

Comment: What's this mania for obfuscating the usual linear search.  The standard idiom for a linear search is `int i = 0; while (i < word1.size() && !isVowel( word1[i] ) ++i; vowelPresent = i != word1.size()`. Assuming you don't want to use iterators, of course, which would be even more idiomatic.

Comment: Yes you are right but then the temporary variable i is visible outside the loop as well. This may or may not be desirable.

Answer (score 1):

This line is the problem:

```
if (word1.find(isVowel) != std::string::npos) {
```

You can't "find" a function pointer inside a `string`.
I suggest using [`std::string::find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of), something like this:

```
if (word1.find_first_of("aeiouAEIOU") != std::string::npos) {
```

With your current approach, you were probably thinking of [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) which *does* take a predicate function. You would use it something like:

```
if (std::find_if(std::begin(word1), std::end(word1), isVowel) != std::end(word1) ) { // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `isVowel` as your search predicate, then you can use `std::find_if`: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/393/